# Unable to read python generated JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I'm pretty new to python. I am trying to generate a JSON array response in python that my javascript application can consume. However, while my javascript recognizes that there are multiple objects within the array, it doesn't recognize any of the keys within those objects. I assume it's due to how I am creating the array and objects in python since I can copy/paste the array to a javascript object and its works perfectly.

Here is an example of my Python 3.7 script:

```
data1 = '{"id": "1", "username": "", "url": "", "icon": "", "display":' + json.dumps(state) +', "mouseover": "", "data":' + json.dumps(Payload) + '}'
data2 = '{"id": "2", "username": "", "url": "", "icon": "", "display":' + json.dumps(state) +', "mouseover": "", "data":' + json.dumps(Payload) + '}'

jsonObj = []

jsonObj.append(data1)
jsonObj.append(data2)

return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'status': "ok",
    'data': jsonObj
}
```

Here is a sample of my javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: Url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.data);

        /*This didn't work --> "undefined"*/
        console.log("WTF?--->" + result.data[0].id)

        /*This didn't work --> "undefined"*/
        Array.from(request.data).forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.id);
        });


        /*This didn't work --> "undefined"*/
        var x = JSON.stringify(result.data);
        var z = JSON.parse(x);
        console.log(z[0].id)

        /*This didn't work --> "undefined"*/
        Array.from(z).forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.id);
        });


    }
})
```

As I said, javascript recognizes there are 2 objects in the array. It's almost as if javascript reads the objects in the array as one key value. The output looks correct and validates as JSON. Not sure what I am doing wrong but I am guessing it has to do with how I am appending the jsonObj as the data key value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check `typeof result.data[0]`. It might be a string, not an object.

Comment: You are correct. And I was able to fix my issue after identifying that by running the result.data object through a foreach and convert it using JSON.parse before pushing it to a new object. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Olian04 putting me on the right track by using typeof to determine whether the objects in the array were truly objects and not strings... I was able to determine that the objects withing the array were in fact actually strings. To resolve the issue I simply ran the array of string through a foreach and converted them to objects.

```
jsonObj = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(result.data, element => {
var converted = JSON.parse(element);
jsonObj.push(converted);
});
```